# How do i check most recent value against values coming from measures retaining row context?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have timeseries data and want to flag if the most recent value fails some criteria.  I have three criteria in the form of measures.  Each measure returns either a blank if no fail or the original value if it does fail.  My measures plot as expected on my chart. However I want to create a callout that identifies if the most recent value fails a criteria and indicates which criteria have failed.

```
Message TARP =

VAR MostRecentDate = MAX( 'AllData'[Date] )

VAR MostRecentValue = CALCULATE(

                            LASTNONBLANK(AllData[Value], TRUE() ),

                            FILTER( AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate )

                         )

VAR Measure1Value = CALCULATE(

                            [Reactive 3Std],

                            FILTER( AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate )

                         )

VAR Measure2Value = CALCULATE(

                            [sudden_change],

                            FILTER(AllData,AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate )

                         )

VAR Measure3Value = CALCULATE(

                            [purple dots measure],

                            FILTER(AllData,AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate )

                         )

 

RETURN

IF( NOT(ISBLANK(MostRecentValue)) && ( NOT(ISBLANK(Measure1Value)) || NOT(ISBLANK(Measure2Value))|| NOT(ISBLANK(Measure3Value))  ),

    "The most recent data point indicates that followup is required",

    BLANK()

)
```

The [sudden_change] measure looks for a 'sudden change' based on another measure using the a rolling mean from the Window function. 'Purple dots' is a measure that checks isblank for a value in a colum and if true, returns blank, otherwise value. And 3StDevs checks if the value is >3 standard deviations from the mean (value) or not (blank).  Plots correctly and displays in a table correctly when Date column is included.
[image: correct output]

In this case, sudden change and Purple dots should be a flag and the output text should read: "The most recent data point..... due to: Sudden Change fail, QA/QC fail"

I think part of the problem is losing the row context in my measures, at least partly due to the rolling average calc, as even when I put that in a table it doesn't display correctly and returns every value equal the value for that day.  Purple dots does work and does display as expected. Reactive 3StDevs does not work (always displays blank). Sudden change always displays blanks too. Can anyone advise how to fix my code or read the bottom line of the table image above and use that to generate my callout?

these are the other measures in use:

```
Rolling Average =

AVERAGEX(

    WINDOW(

        -5,REL,0,REL,

        SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED(AllData), (AllData[Date]),AllData[Attribute],AllData[SiteName] ),

        ORDERBY(AllData[Date]),

        DEFAULT,

        PARTITIONBY(AllData[Attribute])

    ),

    CALCULATE(AVERAGEx(AllData,AllData[Value]))

)


sudden_change = if(SELECTEDVALUE(AllData[Value])>(1.7*[Rolling Average]),SELECTEDVALUE(AllData[Value]),if (SELECTEDVALUE(AllData[Value])<(0.3*[Rolling Average]),SELECTEDVALUE(AllData[Value]),blank()))



Reactive 3Std =

VAR CurrentValue =(max(AllData[Value]))

RETURN

IF(CurrentValue > [3StdDev] , CurrentValue, BLANK())

 

purple dots measure = if(ISBLANK(max(AllData[Purple dot])),blank(),Max(AllData[Purple dot]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the context and how you're trying to obtain the value from the measures. If you're trying to read the bottom line of a table, it means you're trying to get the value corresponding to the latest date. In the "Message TARP" measure, you have correctly tried to identify the most recent date and value. However, it looks like the code is not providing the exact details of which criteria have failed.

```
Message TARP =

VAR MostRecentDate = MAX('AllData'[Date])

VAR MostRecentValue = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(AllData[Value], TRUE()), FILTER(AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate))

VAR Measure1Value = CALCULATE([Reactive 3Std], FILTER(AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate))
VAR Measure2Value = CALCULATE([sudden_change], FILTER(AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate))
VAR Measure3Value = CALCULATE([purple dots measure], FILTER(AllData, AllData[Date] = MostRecentDate))

VAR FailMessage = 
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Measure1Value)), "3 Standard Deviation fail, ", "") & 
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Measure2Value)), "Sudden Change fail, ", "") &
    IF(NOT(ISBLANK(Measure3Value)), "QA/QC fail", "")

RETURN
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(MostRecentValue)) && FailMessage <> "", "The most recent data point indicates that followup is required due to: " & FailMessage, BLANK())
```

The key change here is the `FailMessage` variable that concatenates the error messages for each measure if they have a failure. This will create a string that lists all the failed criteria.

Comment: Thanks, yes I think specifying what has caused the 'fail' is an improvement, but the real issue is I am unable to extract the latest values.  I get blanks when I should be seeing fails.  I think that the window function (rolling average) does not provide the expected result for 'sudden change' making sudden change return blank.  But this doesn't happen when displayed row by row in a table (as shown), which gives the expected result.

Comment: @flashliquid is it possible to share your pbix file ?